# Visual Studio: View Diagnostics Data (Azure)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-diagnostics

I had a working setup for diagnostics in my project which worked fine.
Now all functionality of my Azure worker role is good except collection of diagnostics.
I tried to find out the reason using 'View Diagnostics Data' on Visual Studio's Sever Explorer  like below:

[image]

I am getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol' should always be https for Diagnostcs Connection String.
It works now.